# Google Recaptcha Issue on Showing the in Product Review

Tags: magento-1.9, review, captcha

I have Installed the Google Recaptcha, and i was enabled the extension and entered successfully Site and Security Key. There was no Captcha in the Product Review Tab. Please Anyone Help me.?

I have used this extension.
[enter link description here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/recaptcha-1.html/%22Plugin%20extension%20link%22)

Comment: are u using custom theme?

Comment: yes, i am using custom theme.

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app/design/frontend/theme/theme_sub/template/review/form.phtml
```

Go to above file, what i have to mentioned, and find the ***buttons-set*** and place this code above the **buttons-set** div.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('studioforty9.recaptcha.explicit'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php $recaptcha = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('studioforty9_recaptcha/explicit')->setTemplate('studioforty9/recaptcha/explicit.phtml'); ?>

<?php $this->setChild('studioforty9.recaptcha.explicit', $recaptcha->setAllow(true)); ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('studioforty9.recaptcha.explicit'); ?>
```

Comment: I already tried this but not working.

Comment: have you cleared cache. ?

Comment: okay , sure sir, i will tell once, whether its working or not.

Comment: still not working. even i reindexed too. not working.

Comment: @JohnS i have edited my answer, please try it the same.

Comment: yes, Have Got it, Thanks, your new answer , its working now, thanks,